# Hijack hangs on MacOSX Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, gdb

I just discovered [hijack](https://github.com/ileitch/hijack) for ruby debugging. I installed the gem and gave it a try with thin. I grabbed the id of the thin process and passed it to hijack.

```
$ bundle exec thin start -d -p 3001

$ ps -axf | grep thin
501 52622 34344   0   0:01.90 ttys002    0:07.07 ruby /Users/myself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/thin start -p 3001

$ hijack 52622
=> Hijacking...
```

Instead of giving me an IRB, it stucks after "Hijacking..."

Any ideas?

(OSX 10.6.7, Rails 2.3.8, Ruby 1.8.7)

Comment: A lot of people are seeing hangs on start. See - https://github.com/ileitch/hijack/issues. You should follow up on the issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

Have you [tried Pry](http://pry.github.com/)? It works great and even allows dropping in on controllers etc.  Just awesome, so much so it's my permanent IRB replacement.

Comment: Thanks. Don´t know yet if it is really the thing I´m looking for, but I´ll give it a try.